# Firefoxで画像のはみ出した部分を次のページに印刷するには？

Tags: html, firefox

```
<body>
    <canvas width="500px" height="2000px"></canvas>
    <script>
        var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200, 0, 0)"
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100)
        ctx.fillRect(400, 0, 100, 100)
        ctx.fillRect(0, 1000, 100, 100)
    </script>
</body>
```

上記のhtmlでは、縦2000px、横500pxのcanvasを表示しています。
これを印刷すると、ブラウザによって挙動が違います。

- Google Chrome(40.0.2214.115) 2ページ目が印刷される。下端の四角は次のページに表示
- Firefox(35.0.1) 2ページ目が印刷されない。下の四角は表示されない

FirefoxでChromeのように、画像のはみ出した部分を次ページに印刷する方法はありませんか？

Answer (score 1):

複数の`canvas`に画像を分ければ、この問題を回避できます：

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        div#insatsu {display: none;}
    </style>
    <style type="text/css" media="print">
        canvas#displayCanvas {display: none;}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="displayCanvas" width="500" height="2000"></canvas>

    <div id="insatsu"></div>

    <script>
        var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'),
            ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200, 0, 0)";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
        ctx.fillRect(400, 0, 100, 100);
        ctx.fillRect(0, 1000, 100, 100);

        function createSplitCanvases(canvas, ctx, insatsu) {
            var y = 0,
                SPLIT_Y = 150;

            insatsu.innerHTML = '';

            while (y <= canvas.height) {
                var printCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');

                printCanvas.height = SPLIT_Y < (canvas.height-y) ? SPLIT_Y : (canvas.height-y);
                printCanvas.width = canvas.width;
                insatsu.appendChild(printCanvas);
                insatsu.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
                var ctx2 = printCanvas.getContext('2d');

                ctx2.putImageData(ctx.getImageData(
                    0, y,
                    canvas.width,
                    (y+SPLIT_Y) > canvas.height ? canvas.height : (y+SPLIT_Y)
                ), 0, 0);
                y += SPLIT_Y;
            }
        }

        createSplitCanvases(
            canvas,
            ctx,
            document.querySelector('#insatsu')
        );
    </script>
</body>
```

もちろん、あまり良くない解決策ですが、私の知っている限りでは、Firefoxでは他の方法はないです。`img`という要素を使えば、同じ問題が起こるようです。どなたかより良い方法を知れば是非投稿して下さい。